# No module Flow found for Aimsun/Flow-project

Tags: flow-project

I am trying to run the sugiyama.py example for Aimsun but it keeps failing and the error I get is

> no module named 'flow'".

I have activated the flow environment (instead of the `aimsun-flow`) and I have also modified the `AIMSUN_NEXT_PATH` and `AIMSUN_SITEPACKAGES` directories in the `config.py`.

Could it be related to the Windows 7 OS I am currently using? Or with the Aimsun license I have?

Comment: The error that you get (`no module named 'flow'".`) is always because your system cannot import the Flow package. Are you sure you have done `source activate flow` or `conda activate flow`. Or if you are using Aimsun, did you do `source activate aimsun-flow`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I fixed the problem (no module 'flow') which was related to the aimsun_flow directory. I now get a new error 'No module named flow.controllers'. Any workaround on this one?

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in the next versions of Flow. You can follow the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/flow-project/flow/issues/752). For now, you can change directory to Flow directory (`path/to/flow`) and run examples from there like `python examples/aimsun/sugiyama.py`. Another option is to add the path to Flow directory to PYTHONPATH. You can run `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/flow"` and then run the examples.